# getting gradle to execute JUnit Test (Android app, Android Studio)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, android-studio

I am currently working on an android app and lately switched from Eclipse to Android Studio (wasn't my idea;)). However I want to configure a jenkins server to run JUnit Tests and other tests on a regularly basis. To achieve this, I try to configure a gradle buidlfile. Here is my setup:

Directory structure:

```
-app

    -src
        -main
        -test
```

The build.gradle file: (located in "src/build.gradle)

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

    sourceSets {
        unitTest {
            java.srcDir file('src/test/java/[appName]/app')
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    task unitTest(type:Test) {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'

        unitTest 'junit:junit:4.10'
    }
```

Testclass MainActivityTest.java

```
    package [appName].app;

    import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
    import junit.framework.Assert;

    public class MainActivityTest extends InstrumentationTestCase{

        public void testMain(){
            Assert.assertEquals(1,2);
        }
    }
```

and the most important piece, the error message:

```
    Error:(41, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'unitTest()'!
```

It is my first time working with gradle and Android Studio and I have really no clue what I am doing wrong. On the internet I only find people with similar problems, but no one with a solution which worked for me. I'd be really glad if you could point me in the right direction!

Regards

Comment: `build.gradle` should go into `app`, not into `app/src`. Otherwise, build outputs would go into `app/src/build` (doesn't make much sense), and also the `java.srcDir` path would have to fixed (relative paths are always relative to the build script). Also, the `java.srcDir` path must not include the package names (i.e. it has to be `src/test/java`). Instead of `dependencies { unitTest ...`, it has to be `dependencies { unitTestCompile ... `. I'm not sure if you'll get non-Android source sets just by applying the "android" plugin. You may have to additionally apply "java-base" or "java".

Comment: When using the "java" plugin, you can use the predefined `test` source set (and `testCompile` configuration), rather than declaring your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tell that there is no such property unitTest. Test dependency are declared with instrumentTest (old) or androidTest (New).

Android  sdk comes already with a junit 3 dependency.  So just remove that line

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing doesn't appear to work out of the box in Android Studio. I have a working Gradle configuration that runs unit tests using Robolectric after some minor configurations.

See: [Gradlectric](https://github.com/marcoRS/gradlectric)

Also to specify a different test folder you need to instead use **androidTest**:

```
sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
```